# native base drawer wont open with native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, native-base

i have a problem with native-base and react-native-router-flux.
The Drawer wont open when i click on the menu in the top bar (on snack you see just a questionmark instead of the menu icon) and i don't know whats wrong with the code.

Could anyone help me with this or have a better example then the on on github?

Code is on Snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@snak3/test-with-native-base-drawer-and-native-router-flux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found the solution.

Look at the working Snack Example:
https://snack.expo.io/@snak3/test-with-native-base-drawer-and-native-router-flux

But i have to say that the documentation for react-native-router-flux is the worst i ever saw. Please if your read this here provide more examples and maybe with less stuff around and more comments!